# No implementation found for method getWindowMaximumSize (window_size flutter desktop)

Tags: windows, flutter, flutter-desktop

In my `Flutter desktop` project i'm trying to use [window_size](https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/tree/master/plugins/window_size) plugin (on windows 10) to try to set a maximum size for the window.
I added the plugin in `pubspec.yaml` like below:

dependencies:

```
  ...
  window_size:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding
      path: plugins/window_size
```

And then i'm importing it in `main.dart`:

```
import 'package:window_size/window_size.dart' as window_size;
```

When i call methods like `getWindowMaxSize` or `setWindowMaxSize` i get errors like this:

```
[ERROR:c:\b\s\w\ir\cache\builder\src\flutter\lib\ui\ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getWindowMaximumSize on channel flutter/windowsize)
#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:154:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:329:12)
#2      WindowSizeChannel.getWindowMaxSize (package:window_size/src/window_size_channel.dart:202:32)
#3      getWindowMaxSize (package:window_size/src/window_size_utils.dart:83:37)
```

Is there anything i can do to fix it, maybe by installing a specific plugin version?

Other plugin functions, like `getCurrentScreen` for example are working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those methods are currently implemented only for macOS. You can subscribe to [this issue](https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/issues/483) for updates on Windows and Linux.

Comment: Thanks, now i see, so you don't think i could find another plugin which does the trick? In the link you posted they say "Currently the way you would do this is using NSWindow APIs in the Runner code", but i did not found a way to set the size once i have the .exe file in Runner folder, where can i find it?

Comment: That comment was about macOS, because that's what the issue was filled about initially. You won't find another plugin that does it, because it's currently impossible to do in a plugin in Windows, as discussed in that link. If you want to constrain the size directly in native code for now you could, but it would require familiarity with Win32 programming.

Comment: Yes, i have no familiarity with Win32 programming, i just see a flutter_windows.dll and some other files (Flutter Desktop Example.iobj, .ipdb and .pdb) that could be changed but i don't think it's worth to try. Thank you very much!

Comment: You wouldn't edit build artifacts, you would edit sources.

Comment: With "sources" you mean implementing some method extending `Win32Window` in file `win32_window.h` or something like this, or just editing a file like `window_configuration.cpp` where i can see the constants (like `kFlutterWindowWidth`) to set the size? Becouse i would at least need to set them after build, if not at runtime with a plugin. If i need to program in Win32 even for that i guess i should use a workaround like building my app with three or four different sizes so that the user can choose which one to install

Comment: The window_configuration constants are for initial size, not maximum size. If you want to constrain maximum size you need to change Win32Window.